# Mysql function not returning response to Hibernate

Tags: java, mysql, sql, hibernate

I have a mysql function that is being called from a service class of a web application using HibernateCallback class of Spring. This function selects some rows using a cursor, then does some update and insert. It then returns a varchar.

When the rows selected by cursor are few hundreds, everything is fine. But when number of rows was 12000, the calling java code did not receive any response, even for 1 hour.

When we check in mysql slow query log and error log, it shows that mysql function has run in 8 seconds and lock time was 0.7 seconds. But java program is not getting any response. Also, whenever this function is called, mysql process list goes very high.

What could be the possible reason of no response, when as per mysql logs, function has run?

The function is as follows:

```
CREATE FUNCTION fun_test(
    param1 varchar(15),
    param2 varchar(20),
    v_startTime timestamp,
    v_endTime timestamp)
RETURNS varchar(50) DETERMINISTIC
begin
    declare v_no_more_rows BOOLEAN;
    declare v_id int ;
    declare v_count int default 0;
    declare v_amount double ;
    declare v_totalAmount double default 0;

    DECLARE cur1 CURSOR FOR
        SELECT id,amount 
            from table1 
            where col1=param1 
                and updatedat>= v_startTime 
                and updatedat< v_endTime 
                and amount>0;

    DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR NOT FOUND
            SET v_no_more_rows = TRUE;

    OPEN cur1;
    loop_cur1: LOOP

        FETCH cur1
        INTO v_id,v_amount;
        IF v_no_more_rows THEN
            CLOSE cur1;
            LEAVE loop_cur1;
        END IF;      

        insert into table2 (parentid,createdAt) values(v_id,current_timestamp());
        update table1 
            set updatedat = current_timestamp()
            where
            id = v_id;
            set v_totalAmount=v_totalAmount+v_amount;
            set v_count=v_count+1;

    END LOOP loop_cur1;

    return concat("SUCCESS:",v_totalAmount,":",v_count);

end ;
```

Edit: Adding mysql slow query log results for this function:

```
 Time: 140116 11:22:39
  User@Host: host @  [x.x.x.x]
  Query_time: 7.868044  Lock_time: 0.852301 Rows_sent: 1  Rows_examined: 0
  SET timestamp=1389851559;
  select fun_test('a','b','2014-01-01 11:00:00','2014-01-01 12:00:00');
```

Comment: Could you post the log entries showing the function completing? Is the mysql process CPU use very high for just 7 secs or longer? It would be good to 'prove' your theory that the function is completing before looking into Hibernate/your Java code as one obvious explanation for what you are seeing is that the function isn't in fact completing.

Comment: Check your hibernate session. If table locked in hibernate session and you are trying to insert to the same table by cursor may case this issue.

Comment: @KanagarajM If there is some issue in insert in cursor, how did the mysql function complete in 7 seconds?

Comment: I know this should be the next question but i have faced these type of issue. Hibernate will wait for too much time in this scenario only. Try to debug and post your hibernate log.

Comment: @KanagarajM: As there is no response from function to calling java code, what will I debug in java (or hibernate)?